# Typescript: Encryption using crypto module

Tags: javascript, typescript, cryptojs

I'm trying to encrypt a password using the build in crypto module. I've been using createCipher before which is now deprecated. So I was wondering if a way like this was still a good thing.

Old code:

```
hashPassword(pass: string) {
    const cipher = crypto.createCipher('aes256', 'a pass');
    let encrypted = cipher.update(pass, 'utf8', 'hex');
    encrypted += cipher.final('hex');

    return encrypted;
}
```

I appreciate any kind of suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use something like this from Jyotirmoy Upadhaya

```
const crypto = require("crypto");
const ENC = "bf3c199c2470cb477d907b1e0917c17b";
const IV = "5183666c72eec9e4";
const ALGO = "aes-256-cbc";

const encrypt = (text) => {
  let cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(ALGO, ENC, IV);
  let encrypted = cipher.update(text, "utf8", "base64");
  encrypted += cipher.final("base64");
  return encrypted;
};

const decrypt = (text) => {
  let decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv(ALGO, ENC, IV);
  let decrypted = decipher.update(text, "base64", "utf8");
  return decrypted + decipher.final("utf8");
};

const encrypted_key = encrypt("HelloWorld");
const decrypted_key = decrypt(encrypted_key);

console.log(encrypted_key);
console.log(decrypted_key);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this...
https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/ref_crypto.asp

```
var crypto = require("crypto");

var mykey = crypto.createCipher("aes-128-cbc", "mypassword");
var mystr = mykey.update("abc", "utf8", "hex");
mystr += mykey.final("hex");

console.log(mystr);
```

but it's a weak method without using KEY and IV...